# Display MySQL value in existing div using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Looking to display a value from the 1st record's 'post' field which is stored in a MySQL database using PHP.   The following div is where the value is to be inserted:

```
<div id="insert1"><?php echo($r); ?></div>
```

The PHP (Note using MeekroDB):

```
<?php
require_once 'meekrodb.2.2.class.php';
DB::$user = 'username';
DB::$password = 'password';
DB::$dbName = 'database';
DB::$host = 'hostname';
// get all entries from database table Microblog;
$results = DB::query("SELECT post FROM MicroBlog");
foreach ($results as $row) {
  $id = $row['id'];
  // loop through each entry - there's 3
  for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    // if it's the 1st entry (id = 1) then get field 'post'
    if ($id == 1) {
      $r = $row['post'];
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Currently #insert1 is blank.    What do I need to change to get it into the div? Please note, I want to keep the for loop, as I'll be adding other if's once I get it running.  Thanks.

Comment: at least add the most basic of error checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably this part is wrong:

```
// get all entries from database table Microblog;
$results = DB::query("SELECT post FROM MicroBlog");
```

should be:

```
// get all entries from database table Microblog;
$results = DB::query("SELECT * FROM MicroBlog");
```

You're getting id which i think you're not getting from your query.

```
$id = $row['id'];
```

**Other option:**

Comment out $id.

```
 //$id = $row['id'];
```

and in the if block below, change $id to $i:

```
if ($i == 1) {
      $r = $row['post'];
    }
```

To add number of records:

```
 $x = 0;
    foreach ($results as $row) {
      $x++;
      $id = $row['id'];
      // loop through each entry - there's 3
      for($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
        // if it's the 1st entry (id = 1) then get field 'post'
        if ($id == 1) {
          $r = $row['post'];
        }
      }
    }
echo $x;
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked.  If you don't mind me asking I have a couple of questions on limiting $results:  How could I get the number of records in results? How to limit records to just those starting w/ number,A & B?  How to limit to to 15 records w/ most recent date? (listed from most recent)  Thanks

Comment: Use mysql_num_rows() function so $number_of_records = mysql_num_rows($result);

Comment: Can you help w/ my other questions?

Comment: Post a new one and let's see. If you are willing to study, study first and if you're lost, we are here.

Comment: Ok, for this post, lets just look at your suggestion: $number_of_records = mysql_num_rows($results);  I put that after $results & substituted '3' in for line for $number_of_records, but now nothing in div.

Comment: I just added echo, but it's not printing.

Comment: See my edit if mysql_num_rows is not working for you

Comment: Hmmmm...  See that '3' in the for loop, I need that to be the number of records variable.